# integrating liferay with rails 4 application

Tags: liferay, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am doing app development using ruby on rails 4. Now I prefer to integrate **LIFERAY** with that app. But I don't have any idea that how to integrate it. Guide me through ideas or refer some link to get the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? Run the app on Liferay Platform? Call you app from Liferay? Call Liferay APIs from your app? Something else?

Comment: Well, a long, looong time ago, a colleague developed in RoR using [this](http://rails-portlet.rubyforge.org/). It would demand some courage to try it, however...

Comment: @MilenDyankov I want some features like wiki blog. In that case I decide to use liferay. I want some ideas about further process what I want to do ?

Comment: @brandizzi ,Thanks for the link. And I need more idea about that bcoz I am confused and blank mind about to do. Need some step by step process. Can you explain me?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I'm not Rails expert so I can't go in too many details here. But to answer the

> I want some ideas

question - from system architecture perspective you have 3 options:

- **Front-end is Liferay and some functionalities are provided from external Ruby/Rails apps**. Specific business logic can be developed in Ruby/Rails and exposed via remote services that Liferay will need to call or (if there is UI) embedded via IFrame or inside Liferay's CMS.

  - [PROS]

    - benefit from the flexibility Liferay provides to compose your site/pages, authentication and authorization, templates, collaboration tools, ...
    - develop Ruby/Rails app unconstrained
  - [CONS]

    - additional work to either expose/call services or style the UI in a consistent way.
    - no direct acces to Liferay's API form Ruby
    - need SSO to allow logged in users
- **Front-end is Liferay and some functionalities are provided from Ruby/Rails apps deployed in the portal**. Liferay is written in Java so Ruby is not the most obvious choice here. That said there is a [sample-ruby-portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/master/portlets/sample-ruby-portlet) which demonstrates how to build portlets with Ruby. I'm not a Ruby expert myself. All I know is this is possible via JRuby. Not sure how Rails fits in that picture.

  - [PROS]

    - benefit from the flexibility Liferay provides to compose your site/pages, authentication and authorization, templates, collaboration tools, ...
    - access to Liferay's API form Ruby
    - easier to make consistent look and feel
    - no need for SSO to allow logged in users
  - [CONS]

    - likely some constraints as to what can be done in Ruby
- **Front-end is Rails app and uses some functionalities from Liferay.** Liferay exposes all of it's functionality via JSON-WS services that can be called remotely. Aditionally most (if not all) portlet can be embeded on pages outside Liferay (there is JavaScript snippet provided in each portlet's configuration view).

  - [PROS]

    - develop Ruby/Rails app unconstrained
    - benefit from the some OOTB Liferay functionality
  - [CONS]

    - additional work to either expose/call services or style the UI in a consistent way.
    - no direct acces to Liferay's API form Ruby
    - need SSO to allow logged in users

Obviously you can mix and match as long as you are willing to tolerate the added complexity

Comment: Thanks for ur brief. I converse with my head about this details. Thanks again. Happy Day.

Comment: Here I am using third case. In that case there is no direct API to access LifeRay into Ruby On Rails. Is there anyother way to get API key to integrate liferay into our app.

Comment: Have you tried `http://<your_portal_address>/api/jsonws` or `http://<your_portal_address>/api/axis`? See https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/invoking-remote-services for details.

Comment: And @Milen Dyankov in rails app we use google map. in that case we get gmap API key authentication. Like here, any key are provided by liferay? if yes means, how to get it ?. And how to use that JSONWS API in existing rails app.?

Comment: API keys are used to authenticate apps. In Liferay you need to authenticate users. Thus there are no API keys. Also since there is no state maintained between the remote calls, client need to provide user's credentials with every call. See https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/json-web-services-invocation-examples#get-user-json-web-service-invocation-via-curl for example how to call a service with `curl`. For mobile apps this is a bit easier because we have Android and iOS APIs. There is no such for Rails AFAIK so you could be the one making it and get the credit :)

Comment: Thanks and I want another clarification. This web service works in their liferay platform as localhost:8080. Initially I download liferay 7 CE with tomcat and extract and run it. Now I want to run liferay inside my app platform. but in documentation all are run in portal 8080. Is there any other documents or sample to use liferay in other platform.

Comment: Liferay is a web application that runs inside web container. The port and context are configurable at container level. Check container's documentation for instructions. Also see https://dev.liferay.com/discover/deployment/-/knowledge_base/7-0/installing-liferay-manually for information how to install Liferay manually in custom container.

As for payments - I'm not sure what do you mean. If you refer to the prices of DXP subscriptions, please contact you nearest sales representative. See https://www.liferay.com/contact-us for local offices and online contact form.